# Groovy object id

Tags: groovy

I have a basic groovy question.

When I print a groovy object, it looks like such:

```
groovy:000> f = new Foo()
===> Foo@60410cd
```

How does one get the `60410cd` object id part, given a groovy object?

Comment: what is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo@60410cd` is a result of the `toString()` method, which is using the default method defined on `java.lang.Object`

As defined in the JavaDoc, the default `toString()` will return:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Which, as you can see trails the result with the value of the `hashCode()` method. The default `hasCode()` returns:

"distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)"

So, what you are seeing is the results of the default calls to both `Object.toString()` and `Object.hashCode()`

If you would like to alter the output, you should override the default `toString()` method, something like:

```
String toString(){
    "In Foo!"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo f = new Foo()

Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(f))​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```